# Workaround for async event handler of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: c#

I want to create a bug report in an issue tracker system when an unhandled exception occures. Since this is done by a series of async http requests, the corresponding method is async returning a task:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += async (sender,eventArgs) => 
    await CreateBugReport(eventArgs.ExceptionObject);
```

Unfortunately this does not work, since the message loop terminates before all http requests are done and the CreateBugReport method is not completed.

The alternative

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender,eventArgs) => 
    CreateBugReport(eventArgs.ExceptionObject).Wait();
```

does not work either, it rather hangs forever (which is expected behaviour).

Another constraints is that the method `CreateBugReport` opens a dialog for querying additional information, so it should probably be executed in the UI thread.

What is the best workaround for this issue?

Comment: have you tried Task.Run?

Comment: @Bola: Yes, did not work. It fails when the dialog is created, because it is not done in the UI thread. Not sure if it could deal with the series of async http request anyway.

Comment: If you don't have a logger already then write the exception info into a temp file.  Use the Process class to launch another program, it can do everything you want to do.

Comment: @HansPassant: That should work indeed. Yet, I hoped for a less heavy weight solution.

Comment: Share the code for `CreateBugReport` method.

Comment: What you want to do is too heavy, quite unsafe as well.  Isolating that code in another process makes it safe.

Comment: @Sham: The code for CreateBugReport is quite long. The critical parts of it are `using (var response = await Client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent)){
                return EvaluateResponse(response);
            }` where Client is an instance of HttpClient. Is that enought?

Comment: You need to run this code in a foreground thread. Because background threads can not stop a process/domain from being terminated and your code will not even get chance to run.

Comment: This kind of code is harder to get right than one would expect. If you are not using a logging framework, I think you should add one. If you'd for example use nlog there is a target that is capable to post to a rest api: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target I think you can configure so that it posts on errors only. Logging might feel cumbersome to setup, but when you figure out how to configure the logging you will probably be quite pleased.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it seems that your `CreateBugReport` is going to show UI to the user. Yet, `Wait` hangs due to deadlock and `Task.Run` does not work because there's no UI thread there.

Create a second UI thread just for that dialog (a `LongRunning` task should work. Call `Application.Run` on that new thread again as if it was your Main method.). You can then delay the `UnhandledException` handler until that second thread is done.

Hans Passant says in the comments that this is a bit unsafe and I agree. But it might be an easy and pragmatic solution that just works in practice. If the code which creates the bug report is not sharing data with the code that crashed I don't see why it would not work. The crashed code remains frozen (and it's UI frozen as well).

You also could write the error details to a temp file, relaunch the application and on application start process any such temp files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the separate steps to take. I guess it is really the least heavy approach to take. But then it is not really much lighter than doing the reporting in a separate process as Hans Passant proposed. So I will go with his solution.