# Async methods called from UnhandledException handler don't get awaited

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.7.2

In my `App.xaml.cs`, I have created a handler for responding to the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Inside the handler, I need to call an asynchronous method which sends an email report about the error. So I'm awaiting the method, and inside it I'm awaiting [Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMailAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2).

But this doesn't work -- when the control reaches the second await (right before the actual sending), the application exits.

When I get rid of all async and use the synchronous alternative, [Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=netframework-4.7.2), the email gets sent correctly.

It seems no other exceptions are being thrown inside the handler. Also, it doesn't seem to be just a Visual Studio debugging mode problem.

Is it not possible to successfully call asynchronous methods inside the UnhandledException handler?

**Update:**

The signature of my handler method looks like this:

```cs
private async void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e);
```

and I attach the handler to the event in the constructor of `App` like this:

```cs
App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}
```

Comment: It is possible to reproduce the bad async behavior using a simple ```Task.Delay()``` right in the handler.

Comment: Can you share the signature of your handler method ?

Comment: Related: [Workaround for async event handler of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473887/workaround-for-async-event-handler-of-appdomain-currentdomain-unhandledexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are always `void`. That means that if you want to use `await`, you *must* use `async void`. That's causing the problem you see here.

When `await` acts on an incomplete `Task`, the rest of the method is scheduled for completion after waiting, and it *returns*. Usually it returns a `Task` that the caller can await, but since the return type is `void`, it returns nothing. The caller cannot await it, even if it wanted to. Usually this isn't an issue with events, since events are just a notification that "something" happened and whatever triggered the event isn't dependent on anything that's happening inside the event handler.

But in this case, the framework moves on with shutting down the application after the event handler returns. So since `await` returns, the application shuts down without waiting for the task to actually complete.

Your best solution is to keep everything synchronous in your event handler. This will prevent it from returning before you expect it to.

And by "keep everything synchronous", I mean actually use synchronous methods (like `Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send()`). Don't wait synchronously on asynchronous methods, since that [can cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Oops, sorry. I pasted the synchronous version of the handler which I temporarily resorted to. The signature did contain `async`.

Comment: @zvizesna Yes, I figured you were using `async void` already. That's what my answer addresses. You need to remove the `async` and only use synchronous methods inside your handler.

Comment: The general advice is never use `async void` unless you absolutely have to.  It has unique behaviors compared to any other async return type, and will tend to cause hiccups like this that are not immediately obvious.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny I wouldn't say "never". The fact that it's not completely disallowed by the compiler means that it has its place. [Microsoft uses the word "avoid"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) with the only exception being event handlers (i.e. the only acceptable use is in event handlers). However, there are events like this one where some other thing happens immediately after the event handler finishes, where `async void` just isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, that's mostly what I was echoing.  I meant "general advice => never" to approximate "if you don't know for a fact you need to use this, don't"